# How to efficiently sort by the results of a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, sql-order-by

Let's say I have a site like Stackoverflow with posts that people can reply to, and I would like to have an interface for sorting the posts by reply count

This will eventually have infinite scroll pagination, so showing 10 results at a time.

Here's an example query for that:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM post_reply pr 
           WHERE pr.convo_id = post.convo_id) as replies 
FROM post 
ORDER BY replies 
LIMIT 10;
```

This works, but it is prohibitively slow. I have hundreds of thousands of posts and this causes the query to take >30s to complete.

An index would improve the speed, but I have no idea how to implement an index on a subquery.

A materialized view could also work, but updating the materialized view every time someone replies to a post seems prohibitively slow as well.

Is there a good solution to this problem?

Comment: Indexes are physical data structures they aren't something that exists at a query level (aside from a query hint that would force usage of a specific index). That is, to say, indexes are created on a table, not a subquery. Can you provide the existing table structure (like the CREATE statements)? In SQL Server, the engine will use the smallest/narrowest index for COUNT purposes. I am not sure if it's the same in postgres.

Comment: @JacobH There isn't really much to the table structure. `post` and `post_reply` both have `convo_id` fields (one to many relationship), and they both have `TEXT` body fields. There's some other columns but they aren't really too relevant to this question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really speed up this query.

You can change the data model and use a lot of infrastructure to get a faster sort.  The idea is:

1. Add a column `post_reply_count` to the `posts` table.
2. Add an index on this column.
3. Keep this column up-to-date using triggers -- `+ 1` for `insert`, `- 1` for `delete`.  And whatever is appropriate for `update`.
4. Use this column in your query.

This adds overhead.  But if you really need a speed response to this query, you may not have a choice.

Comment: That sounds okay, but I don't really know how performant triggers are. I guess I'll have to google that. Any opinions on the preference of triggers vs running a job that updates all posts every 10 min or so with their respective post count?

Comment: @RyanPeschel . . . Basically they add a little bit of overhead to each DML operation.  Unless your database is under a heavy load, you probably won't notice it.

Answer (score 1):

You could change order of queries and first generate list of posts by reply count and then get `post` columns. This should use primary key (I'm assuming `post.convo_id` is one) and potentially be faster, tho I do not guarantee it will.

```
SELECT post.*, sub.replies
  FROM (SELECT pr.convo_id, COUNT(*) AS replies
          FROM post_reply pr
         GROUP BY pr.convo_id
         ORDER BY replies --maybe DESC if you want top reply count first
         LIMIT 10
       ) AS sub
  JOIN post USING(convo_id);
```

Comment: From 30 seconds to 3 milliseconds. Very clever!

Comment: @RyanPeschel This is odd change. Maybe you do not have index on `post_reply.convo_id`? I did try this approach on tables with one to many relation and did have some speed increase (like 20%) but I attributed that to use of multi column index on "many" table. Or I just have completely different data set (no comments/posts table).